React Mui card refresh on react / Component refresh
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { Grid, Card, CardContent, Box} from '@mui/material';
import MainCard from 'components/MainCard';
import UploadGP from './components/UploadGP';
import UploadExcel from './components/UploadExcel';
import UploadDataTable from './components/UploadDataTable';

export default function FCRUpload() {
  return (
    <MainCard title="Foreign Currency Risk">
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        {/* Top: Long card spanning full width */}
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Box>
            <Card>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
                  Upload Excel File Here
                </Typography>
                <UploadExcel />
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </Box>
        </Grid>

        {/* Bottom: Two cards side by side */}
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <Box mt={2}>
            <Card>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
                  Uploaded Foreign Currency Risk Details
                </Typography>
                <UploadDataTable />
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </Box>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <Box mt={2}>
            <Card>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
                  Enter Gold Position
                </Typography>
                <UploadGP />
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </MainCard>
  );
}

this is my code which has 3 cards each carrying a method now I need to refresh other cards if one card gets changes
The first card has an Excel upload that sends data to the back end and inserts them into a table. The second card gets those data and shows them in a grid, but as the current code doesn't work, the grid shows old values.
I tried putting tab refresh, but it is not user-friendly. Is there a way I can refresh other cards if an action happens in one of them?
